# How is an Integer converted to ASCII in Java Behind the Scenes?

Tags: java, encoding, binary, ascii

I'm not asking for a built-in class that accomplishes this, I'm just curious on how encoding works behind the scenes in java. For example, An integer in java can be stored in 4 bytes, between -2147483648 and 2147483647. Lets use 500 as the number for this demonstration. From what I understand, the computer initially stores this number in memory as 1F4 in hex, which is 00000000 00000000 00000001 11110100 in binary. When I looked up how ASCII works, it encodes each digit 0-9 to its corresponding ASCII value (0 translates to 048). However, how is the binary number stored in ram able to separate each digit so that each digit can be encoded to its corresponding ASCII value? We know that the number is 500, but this is just an abstraction. The computer just sees 1's and 0's. So how is the 5 mapped to 053, and both 0's mapped to 048 for this example. Does the jvm account for this automatically behind the scenes? Or am I misunderstanding how the entire process works. Thanks.

Comment: A Java character is a 16-bit integral type.  An [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) contains the 127 valid ascii characters and their mapping to integer constants. Normally, the process of encoding that mapping into a programming language is "stage 1" of a three stage bootstrap process. This is not unique to Java. See also [Reflections on Trusting Trust](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rdriley/487/papers/Thompson_1984_ReflectionsonTrustingTrust.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

Well, IF I understand your question directly...

You could start by dividing your integer by 10 and getting the remainder -- the `mod` function in Java (%) is useful for this.

```
int digitInteger = originalNumber % 10;
```

The digitInteger variable now holds a number 0-9, the integer version of the ASCII (or Unicode, or whatever) of the *last* digit in the number. Unfortunately for your example, this will be a fairly boring 0.

Let us instead use the number 543 as our example, it will make things easier. If originalNumber was 543, then digitInteger will now be 3. Since 48 represents ASCII 0, then you can add that to digitInteger to get the ASCII equivalent. I'll leave it to you put that somewhere, since Java does not deal with ASCII as its default encoding. (Unicode, I believe, has the same values as ASCII for these digits).

Now you execute something like

```
originalNumber = originalNumber / 10;
```

This *integer* division will truncate the digit you just isolated, 3 in our case, and originalNumber is now 54.

You repeat this process - mod by 10 to isolate the last digit, convert to character, prepend to characters previously found, integer divide by 10 to truncate the last digit -- until originalNumber is 0 -- digitInteger, as you can probably see now, will be 4 on the next round and 5 on the round after that, and you prepend those to the 3 you got the first time to get your ASCII equivalent.

Comment: Althought this was useful information, I stated in the question that I wanted to know how java operates and does this behind the scenes. Not how to implement it myself. Are you saying java does this process? I'm just confused how a number that is declared an int in java, is encoded so a text editor can understand its ascii representation.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the open source version of things, be aware this might be in C, which is often used for low-level implementation stuff in Java. I think it has to be some equivalent of this; I cannot imagine there is any way to determine what the digits are except some form of this. The binary integer form does not lend itself for any easier conversion to a string form.

Comment: It's not a function, and it isn't 'mod'. It is a remainder operator.

Comment: You are right that it is an operator. It gets referred to as 'mod' as short for 'modulus' or 'modulo', which is the mathematical term for the operation.